# insert into table values(int ,int ,time ,time ) Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

This is the table i created and i want insert a value in it

```
Create Table JunctionRS(
id_r int foreign key references Rute(id_r),
id_s int foreign key references Statii(id_s),
constraint id_j primary key (id_r,id_s),
arrival time,
departure time);




insert into JunctionRs values(1 , 2 , 21:45:00 ,22:00:00 );
```

Comment: You have to single quote your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some quotes to your times

```
insert into JunctionRS values(1 , 2 , '21:45:00','22:00:00' );
```

Comment: Wow thanks Gordon. AutoCorrect on mobile went haywire and I didn't catch it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i didn't know that i must write it as varchar

Comment: No worries @Esan. Generally speaking you need to quote anything that can't be treated as a number